# Read a huge log file line by line and random access in node?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, low-level-io

I'm working on a log file reader which will parse files and display fields from lines in a nicely formatted table in a node/electron app.

If the files were small, I could just read them line-by-line, parse them, store fields extracted from each line in a data structure and allow clients to scroll back and forth throughout the whole the file.

Since these files can be several gigabytes long, I need to do something more complex.

My current thinking is to either:

1. Read the whole file via the readline package.
2. Keep track of line ending offsets
3. Once the file is read, parse the bottom (hence most recent) 50 or so lines so I can extract relevant data and display visually
4. If client wants to scroll beyond my 50 lines, use the offsets to go to previous lines (via fs.read(..)).

Another method:

1. Use fs.read() to go straight to the end
2. Work backwards until newline characters are found
3. If client wants to scroll around the file, figure out the line offsets on demand

This doesn't even take into account building `tail -f` style functionality.

I'll have to account for at least `ascii` and `utf8` encodings, as well as windows vs linux style line endings.

This is a LOT of low level work.

Is there a library which already provides functionality?

If I do this myself, any major caveats I haven't mentioned here? I haven't done low level, random access, programming for 20 years.

Comment: Questions asking for a third party library to solve your problem are considered "off topic" here.

Comment: Your second method is more scalable for very large files and more memory efficient and would give a lot quicker result if doing tail-like functionality on large files.  It would be more work to code to find lines while searching backwards through the file, but infinitely more flexible.